# Remove duplicate object from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I wanted to remove all duplicated object in an array. But it doesn't work

```
var a = [{name: 'user-test'}, {6: 7}, {6: 7}, {name: 'user-test'}];
    _.uniq(a);
```

It returns: `[{name: 'user-test'}, {6: 7}, {6: 7}, {name: 'user-test'}]`
Expected: `[{name: 'user-test'}, {6: 7}]`

Can anyone give me an answer?

Comment: all items/objects are unique.

Comment: 200+ rep and cannot search for _remove duplicate objects from array underscore_ ??

Comment: @mplungjan: I feel like an idiot. Of **course** there's a previous version of this question. Thank you for marking that.